# Does longtable not support the m column type?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have the following problem: I would like to use the `m` column type in a `longtable`. But if I typeset

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{p{5cm}m{5cm}}
        skdlbf & asljkdh\\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I get an error about an `Illegal character in array arg` in the line of `\begin{longtable}{..}`. If I change the `m` to a `p`, all runs well.

So why does `longtable` not support the `m` (and `b`) column type? Am I missing a package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\usepackage{array}
```

That's the solution.